# Flutter YouTube video embedded

Tags: flutter

I want to add a YouTube video embedded in my application: How can I do it? I have this

```
import 'package:youtube_player/youtube_player.dart';
import 'package:flutube/flutube.dart';

 class Videos extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Canal Youtube'),
          ),
          body: YoutubePlayer(source: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuBxtXWWheiQAs-uiJfU5tQ", quality: YoutubeQuality.HD),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [youtube_player_flutter](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter) package to play YouTube videos. - Follow the instruction on Installing tab. Then try to run the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: 'iLnmTe5Q2Qw',
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: true,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Youtube test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: YoutubePlayer(
          controller: _controller,
          showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
          progressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
          onReady: () {
            print("player ready..");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you like to see more options, you can also take a look at a more detailed example: [here](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/tree/master/example)

Answer (score 1):

[Neeko](https://pub.dev/packages/neeko) is a Simple video player widget based on video_player. Neek supports more actions such as timeline control, toggle fullscreen and so on.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

//  static const String beeUri = 'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4';
  static const String beeUri =
      'http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/03/09/mp4/190309153658147087.mp4';


  final VideoControllerWrapper videoControllerWrapper = VideoControllerWrapper(
      DataSource.network(
          'http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/03/09/mp4/190309153658147087.mp4',
          displayName: "displayName"));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
    super.dispose();
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Scaffold(
      body: NeekoPlayerWidget(
        onSkipPrevious: () {
          print("skip");
          videoControllerWrapper.prepareDataSource(DataSource.network(
              "http://vfx.mtime.cn/Video/2019/03/12/mp4/190312083533415853.mp4",
              displayName: "This house is not for sale"));
        },
        videoControllerWrapper: videoControllerWrapper,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.share,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print("share");
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```